# Are there any writings on the parallels between Moses’ return to Egypt from Midian and the Incarnation?

Tags: incarnation, moses

Pretty much in the title. I was listening to a sermon where the incarnation had some significant parallels with Moses’ departure from Midian- namely, someone stepping out from comfort and paradise to live amongst God’s people and rescue them. I can’t seem to find any writings or material that address this - is it a commonly agreed upon concept?